# Inserting null into MySQL using an PHP array. PDO prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some information that is sent from my client to my server in the following format:

```
{
    identifier: {
        value: null,
        public: false
    }
}
```

Obviously the value isn't always null, but there are times when it needs to be, when sending this over to PHP it saves "null" as a String during the `json_decode` phase.  When trying to insert null values into the SQL database, instead of `NULL` I get `"null"` which is causing strange things to happen on my client. (IE: Displaying "null" instead of nothing).

Obviously I could just do a check on the client for "null" but I see no reason to continuously spend the additional bytes of data to send the text "null" to the client.

EXAMPLE:

```
$identifier = $json_array['identifier'];
$statement = $connection->prepare("UPDATE table SET v1 = :val, p1 = :pub");
$statement->bindParam(":val", $identifier['value']);
$statement->bindParam(":pub", $identifier['public']);
$statement->execute();
```

Where v1 is a VARCHAR value

Answer (score 0):

ALWAYS *verify* your ideas.

> it saves "null" as a String during the json_decode phase.

Wrong.

```
$json = '{
    "identifier": {
        "value": null,
        "public": false
    }
}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj);
```

clearly says value is null.
Which, in turn, gets inserted all right in MySQL using an PHP array and PDO prepared statement.

Comment: How would you know OP's assumption of null being converted to a string value "null" is incorrect? They didn't specify what kind of client sends that data, how the data is encoded to JSON, how it is send to the server, etc... I have had the same problem as what OP describes; a null value in a JSON object on the client suddenly being a "null" value when it arrives on the server.

Comment: @kevin Because I happen to know how do PHP, PDO and mysql work. And such a scenario is just impossible. Just like the OP, you have to **verify your data.** Did you bother to check what "json" you get? What php array you have after decode? Why blame mysql and PDO if you aren't certain about the data you get?

Comment: I was talking about an encoding problem on the client side, PHP PDO and mysql have nothing to do with that.

Comment: Because the example he provided.